# Filezilla + hostgator transfer failed rosyln

Tags: asp.net-mvc, roslyn, file-transfer, filezilla, csc

I am using Hostgator as a hosting service and using FileZilla software to upload my files.

I have my published application which was built in Asp.Net MVC C#.

When I trasnfer my published code through FileZilla it transferred my all code except following files.

csi.exe, vbc.exe, csc.exe, VBCSCompiler.exe

[image]

I don't understand why these files have not been accepted.

Anyone having the same issue before or solution how to transfer these files.

Comment: Your question is [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). And you should contact your *hosting provider* about your problem anyway.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After discussion with hosting provider (Hostgator).

They confirmed that they are not accepting exe files anymore in shared hosting because they were attacked by hackers last year with exe nonsense. How can I be assure about my application is safe there?

They didn't even mentioned that thing when I was confirming from them before purchasing hosting space such nonsense promises.

Such a nonsense hosting provider company it is showing something different and inside there is something different.

Hostgator has ruined my money and time.

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy even without Roslyn with no change in code.

Open NuGet Package Manager window and uninstall Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform package and rebuild & republish.

This uninstallation also removes CodeDom configuration from web.config file.

This will solve your purpose.

Basically this will not generate any csc.exe, vbc.exe files inside bin folder.